# How to split string and add custom character in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have following strings :

```
   str1 - 12345,67890,9999,0000
   str2 - 5839
```

Now i want to split , add character and join string again.

My final output :

```
str1 -  ''12345'',''67890'',''9999'',''0000''
str2 -  ''5839''
```

Comment: You need to Learn about string.split and [string.join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: These should get you started: https://www.dotnetperls.com/split 
  https://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working properly. I have tried String.Join("''", array);

Comment: `string result = string.Join(",", source.Split(',').Select(item => $"''{item}''"));`

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<=,|^)[^,]*(?=,|$)", @"''$0''");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample below

```
var str1 = "12345,67890,9999,0000";
var str2 = "5839";
var result1 = "''" + string.Join("'',''", str1.Split(',')) + "''";
var result2 = "''" + string.Join("'',''", str2.Split(',')) + "''";
Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply use the `Replace()` method to replace instances of `","` with `"'',''"`, while also adding `"''"` to both ends of the string:

```
var input = "12345,67890,9999,0000";

var result = $"''{input.Replace(",", "'',''")}''";

// result == "''12345'',''67890'',''9999'',''0000''"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using `String.Split()`, a `loop` and then `String.Join` like this

```
string str1  =   "12345,67890,9999,0000";
var strArr = str1.Split(',');

for(int i=0; i<strArr.Length;i++){

    strArr[i] = "''"+strArr[i]+"''";
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", strArr));  

// output = ''12345'',''67890'',''9999'',''0000''
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function:

```
public string splitFunction(string strAttached, string strSpecialChar, char chrSplitChar = ',', bool blnTrimValues = true)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<string> result;

        if (blnTrimValues)
            result = strAttached.Split(chrSplitChar).Select(strValue => strSpecialChar + (string)strValue.Trim() + strSpecialChar);
        else if (strSpecialChar == "")
            result = strAttached.Split(chrSplitChar);
        else
            result = strAttached.Split(chrSplitChar).Select(strValue => strSpecialChar + strValue + strSpecialChar);

        return string.Join(chrSplitChar.ToString(), result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Usage and results:

```
string res = splitFunction("12345,67890,9999 ,0000 ", "''", ',', true);
// Result: ''12345'',''67890'',''9999'',''0000''

string res = splitFunction("5839", "''", ',', true);
// Result: ''5839''

string res = splitFunction("A,B,C,D", "$", ',', true);
// Result: $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$

string res = splitFunction("Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4", "**");
// Result: **Val1**,**Val2**,**Val3**,**Val4**
```